# What's wrong with my jQuery? Trying to make it change the background color dependent on what the user picks?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to the user to select an option from a drop down box and have the value of the selected option be stored as a cookie, and then that value is set to the page background, or the gallery background, or both, dependent on the button the user picks. This doesn't appear to be working, however.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#set_cookie').click(function() {

        var color = $('#set_cookie').val();

        $.cookie('test_cookie', color);

        $('#set_page').click(function() {
            $('body').css('background', color);
        });

        $('#set_gallery').click(function() {
            $('#gallery').css('background', color);
        });

        $('#set_both').click(function() {
            $('body').css('background', color);
            $('#gallery').css('background', color);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Included scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="media/header.png" alt="Community Header" />
            </div>

            <p>Please select a background color for either the page's background, the gallery's background, or both.</p>

            <select id="set_cookie">
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                <option value="darkblue">Dark Blue</option>
                <option value="darkbrown">Dark Brown</option>
                <option value="darkgreen">Dark Green</option>
                <option value="darkred">Dark Red</option>
                <option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="grey">Grey</option>
                <option value="#d3d3d3">Light Grey</option>
                <option value="#32cd32">Lime Green</option>
                <option value="#f8b040">Macaroni</option>
                <option value="#ff7300">Orange</option>
                <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="#0fcce0">Turquoise</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" id="set_page" value="Page's Background" /><input type="button" id="set_gallery" value="Gallery's Background" /><input type="button" id="set_both" value="Both" />

            <p>Community is an American television comedy series created by Dan Harmon that airs on NBC. The series is about a group of students at a community college in the fictional locale of Greendale, Colorado. The series heavily uses meta-humor and pop culture references, often parodying film and television clichés and tropes. The series premiered Thursday, September 17, 2009, and airs in the 8:00 pm ET time slot. It previously aired in the 9:30 pm ET time slot, beginning with its premiere, but later relocated with its fourth episode. On March 17, 2011, NBC renewed Community for a trd season, wch premiered on September 22, 2011.</p>

            <div id="gallery">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/abed_annie_troy.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Abed, Annie and Troy"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/abed_annie_troy.jpg" alt="Abed, Annie and Troy" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/annie_paintball.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Annie playing paintball"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/annie_paintball.jpg" alt="Annie during the first paintball episode" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/annie.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Annie's Halloween costume"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/annie.jpg" alt="Annie as a skeleton" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/britta_dinosaur.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Jeff's and Britta's Halloween costumes"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/britta_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Britta's and Jeff's Halloween costumes" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_cafeteria.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the cafeteria"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_cafeteria.jpg" alt="The cast in the cafeteria" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_class.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the classroom"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_class.jpg" alt="The cast in a classroom" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_cloud.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Tnking"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_cloud.jpg" alt="The cast tnking" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_mural.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In front of a colorful chalkboard"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_mural.jpg" alt="Cast in front of a chalkboard" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_study_room.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Hanging in the study room"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_study_room.jpg" alt="The cast in their study room" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the library"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast.jpg" alt="The cast" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/christmas_episode.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Transformed into Christmasy claymation characters"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/christmas_episode.jpg" alt="Claymation Christmas episode" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/pierce.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Pierce hears sometng!"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/pierce.jpg" alt="Pierce with other students" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/season_3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="The introduction to season 3"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/season_3.jpg" alt="Intro to season three" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/show_poster.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="The classic Community poster"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/show_poster.jpg" alt="Poster for the show" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/troy_and_abed.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Troy and Abed In the Morning!"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/troy_and_abed.jpg" alt="Troy and Abed In The Morning" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/trio_paintball.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="After an intense paintball match"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/trio_paintball.jpg" alt="Troy, Annie and Abed after paintball" /></a></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What happens? Anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want [`$('#set_cookie').change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)? Also, to get the `.val()` of the selected, you'll need to [`$('#set_cookie option:selected').val()`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

Comment: I created a jsfiddle of your existing code which may help.  You would need to add shadowbox via a url.  It's at http://jsfiddle.net/j5z3B/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% positive that the cookie plugin script is loaded? Because everything works fine without the call to `$.cookie(...)` for me.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hu6DP/

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Now to fix it given the other guy's help, then to reply to him... Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit strange to me, that you are defining the click handler for set_page within the click handler for set_cookie.  Also that you are attempting to reference the "color" variable within that handler.  In any case, I'd try changing it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#set_cookie').click(function() {

        var color = $('#set_cookie').val();

        $.cookie('test_cookie', color);
    });


        $('#set_page').click(function() {
            if ($.cookie('test_cookie')) $('body').css('background-color',  $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        });

        $('#set_gallery').click(function() {
            if ($.cookie('test_cookie')) $('#gallery').css('background-color', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        });

        $('#set_both').click(function() {
            if ($.cookie('test_cookie')) $('body').css('background-color', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
            if ($.cookie('test_cookie')) $('#gallery').css('background-color', $.cookie('test_cookie'));
        });
```

});

*Updated to fix the reference to background-color*

Comment: Well, when the page, gallery, and "both" event handlers are defined outside of the "set_cookie" method, it's possible to call them before the cookie is set.  I thought it would be a good idea to verify the value has been set before attempting to use it.

Comment: I think I noticed the problem - the css property should be "background-color", not just "background".